# Database access design pattern

Tags: android, database, sqlite, design-patterns

I would like to develop an Android application which will have a local database.

I also have a web service to retrieve data and store them on that local database.

Which design pattern do you recommend me for database access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar in the past and I used dao pattern. I had a Dao class for each domain entity of my application (e.g. UserDao, BookDao, etc) and a helper class to manage database creation (a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper).